# Popup don't reappears when we quit the app without killing the app Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, popup

Good morning I have a problem, when I enter to my app a popup appears with the func viewDidAppear() but when for example I click on the "No" button that quit the app proprely like when we push the home button. When I re-enter in the app without killing it the popup doesn't reappears...

I search for 3 hours and I don't find the solution...

Here is the code:

```html
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if warning == true{
            self.alertStart()
        }
    }
    
    func alertStart(){
        let alertatstart = UIAlertController(title: "ATTENTION !", message: "La version de cette application est en cours de bêta, de nombreux bug sont à déclarer, souhaitez-vous tout de même continuer ?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertatstart.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Oui", style: .destructive, handler:{ (UIAlertAction) in
            self.warning = false
            if self.betaKeyAlreadyConfirmed == true {
                
            }else{
               self.askDevMail()
            }
        }))
        alertatstart.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Non", style: .cancel, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
            self.warning = true
            UIControl().sendAction(#selector(URLSessionTask.suspend), to: UIApplication.shared, for: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alertatstart, animated: true)
    }
```

I have already tried to put the func into the viewDidLoad() but it doesn't work...

I hope you will help me, thank you a lot, if you need more informations tell me in the answers

Louis.

Answer (score 5):

`ViewDidAppear` doesn't gets called when you press Home button and come back again.

Use Notifications for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` and `UIApplicationWillResignActive`:

In `ViewDidLoad` :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.callBackForActiveNotification), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.callBackForBackgroundNotification), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
```

Add functions:

```
@objc func callBackForBackgroundNotification(){
   // This will be called when your app goes in background
}

@objc func callBackForActiveNotification(){
   // This will be called when your app become active, show pop up here again if it is not shown
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I try but it doesn't work I click on no and I don't get the popup again when I come back to the app. The NotificationCenter code doesn't work on my Xcode it appears to be an error

Comment: @LouisLegout yes because of this **self.warning = true** check there. In No you are setting it as false. So this will never be called again if its false **if warning == true{
            self.alertStart()
        }**.

Comment: Obviously, I have correct my error, I haven't any errors now I try what you say. Thanks you again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it on **ViewWillAppear** or **AppDelegate** level.
On **AppDelegate** level, it should work.

When you click **Home** button, app go to background mode. Otherwise, app will go to foreground mode if you open app again.

In appdeletegate.m (appdelegate.swift-Swift) file, you can see follow functions.

applicationDidBecomeActive and applicationWillDidEnterBackground. you can put your code there.

here is official [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()   
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
     print("keyboardWillShow")
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification){
     print("keyboardWillHide")
}
```

Comment: check your answer what you are posting the question is about showing popup not keyboardwillshow or hide

Comment: it works thank you I have put in the wrong place Notification Center observer.